# Custom Calculation in Laravel Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-controller

I am new to Laravel. I'm building a small app which displays the user table from the DB, but before sending it to the view, I want to include a custom value from another function.

The accounts table fetches the list of accounts from MySQL, and I want to include a custom function called `getStatus()` which I get from an API.

**Code**

```php
<?php

public function accounts()
{
    $accounts = DB::table('accounts')
        ->where('profile_id', '=', Auth::id())
        ->get();

    foreach ($accounts as $account) {

        $account->status = getStatus($account->accno);
    }

    $data = compact('accounts');

    return view::make('transactions', ['accounts' => $data]);
}
```

**View**

```
@foreach ($accounts as $account)
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>{{ $account->login }}</td>
        <td>{{ $account->status }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
$accounts = $accounts->map(function($account){
   $account->status = getStatus($account->accno)
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Thanks

Comment: Worked like a charm. Solved. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$accounts = DB::table('accounts')
    ->where('profile_id', '=', Auth::id())
    ->get()
    ->map(function($item){
       $item->status = getStatus($item->accno);
       return $item;
    });
```

Now you'll have status in your `$accounts`.